# AngularJs - Modal dialog that embed views by ui-view

Tags: angularjs

My goal is to have a **modal view with couple of buttons and a ui-view**. When clicking one of those buttons it will load the specific view + controller.

Reading from the angular-ui router project (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) they control ui-views with states. **How could I do that with a modal?**

Below you can get a better idea of what i am aiming for. I tried also using states (abstract state to load layout template with buttons leaving a ui-view directive) but it didnt work. Any ideas on how to organize the code to accomplish it?

This is the code to launch the modal view:

```
$scope.launchModalView = function(data){

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    controller: 'coversModalController',
    size: 'lg',
    templateUrl: 'partials/covers.modal.html',
    resolve: {
        data: function(){
            return data;
        }
    }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
        console.log('Got it! Song  = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
}
```

Here the coversModalController:

```
admintoolApp.controller('coversModalController',function($scope, $modalInstance, data){
    // Modal functionality
    $scope.data = data;

    $scope.submit = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.data);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Here we have the template "partials/covers.modal.html":

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Select one method to choose images</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <ul>
            <li>From Private Library</li>
            <li>From External Resource</li>
            <li>Upload image</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;" ui-view>
        <h4>Choose one of the options from your left</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```